# Nginx redirect to 8080 without DNS

Tags: server, java, nginx

Is it possible to perform a proxy_pass with nginx without having a DNS?

I was able to configure the SSL in the servers that I have the the DNS, which are the QA and Production environment in my company, but I am not being able to configure the DEV environment at all, but there is no DNS for it.

This is the configuration that I've used for SSL in QA environment, **which is working correctly**:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  server_name myweb.com.br;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}


server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

  server_name myweb.com.br;

  ssl_certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/myweb.com.br/fullchain.pem";
  ssl_certificate_key "/etc/letsencrypt/live/myweb.com.br/privkey.pem";

  ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

  ssl_dhparam "/etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem";
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
  ssl_session_timeout 10m;
  ssl_ciphers HIGH:SEED:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!RSAPSK:!aDH:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA:!SRP;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  root /var/www;
  index index.html index.htm;

  location / {
    #Enable reverse proxying to Wildfly on internal port 8080  
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;

    #Tell NGINX to proxy these headers
    proxy_set_header sec_jbossremoting_key $http_sec_jbossremoting_key;
    proxy_set_header sec_hornetqremoting_key $http_sec_hornetqremoting_key;
    proxy_set_header upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header host $http_host;
  }

}
```

I've tried to do a shorter version of this, since I am not expert in the topic, or to use the default configuration with an ip port bound to it, but I just get bad gateway and in the logs I have nothing, just that an access was attemped.

```
10.22.2.36 - - [09/Mar/2020:08:06:06 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36" "-"
10.22.2.36 - - [09/Mar/2020:08:06:06 -0300] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "http://10.233.133.6/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

The nginx working in my local machine is simple enough, basically using what the default conf brought with it.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

I've tried modifying this basic configuration in the server to its IPs but all without success. The ports are open already, both 80 and 8080 are accessible and I can see the nginx in the 80 and my wildfly in the 8080.

Can someone assist me with this? Or tell me if it is possible to do so without a DNS having it bound only to IP address.

Answer (score 0):

try the following config for Nginx redirection

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name _;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;

        }
        location /.git {
            deny all;
            return 404;
        }
}
```